# Parse an URL-path based rest API

Tags: swift, url

I'm create a client app using a REST API. This one use a URL-path format, i.e `/api/subPath/{variable}/otherSubPath`

I know Apple gives a `URLComponents` class but seems to work very well only for `URL-query-argument` i.e `/api/path?param=value`

I would like to create a class `URLBuilder` for giving me the different API url dynamically. For the moment I ended up with a class who looks like this:

```
class URLBuilder {
  fileprivate static let base = "https://theAPI.com/"
  fileprivate static let objectsPath = kBase + "objects/"

  static func informationOfObject(withID id: Int) {
    return objectsPath + "\(id)/" + "information/"
  }

  // Many other functions like this
}
```

So I would like to know how to get something more elegant (if possible) and maybe use URL-path format with `URLComponents`.
Or maybe should I use regex? I've never use it but maybe it's useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into using the `append...` family of functions from `URL`?

- [appendPathComponent(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780397-appendpathcomponent)
- [appendPathComponent(_:isDirectory:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780403-appendpathcomponent)
- [appendingPathComponent(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780239-appendingpathcomponent)
- [appendingPathComponent_:isDirectory:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779992-appendingpathcomponent)

If I understand your requirements, you can do something like:

```
let baseURL = URL(string: "/api/subPath")!
let variableURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("variable")
let trailingURL = variableURL.appendingPathComponent("otherSubPath")
print(trailingURL.absoluteString)
```

Output: **`api/subPath/variable/otherSubPath`**

You could even chain the `appending` calls together if you need it on a single line.